# Determining the version of Java SDK on the Mac

Tags: java, macos

I have a MacBook Pro running Snow Leopard;  how can I see what version of the Java SDK is installed on my Mac?

Comment: You'll get much better answers if you properly tag your questions, properly word your questions and **accept answers**

Comment: What's difference between JDK and SDK ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions` you'll see all the installed JDKs. There is a symbolic link named `CurrentJDK` pointing the active JDK.

Comment: in terminal: javac -version

Comment: I'm confused, in `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/` I found that `CFBundleVersion` = 15.0.1, while running `java -version` returned 1.7.0_71. I know that my JDK version is 1.7.0_71, so what is 15.0.1?

Answer (score 113):

Open a terminal and type: `java -version`, or `javac -version`.

If you have all the latest updates for Snow Leopard, you should be running JDK 1.6.0_20 at this moment (the same as Oracle's current JDK version).

Comment: Intriguing, as it breaks the common convention of `--long_word`. I tried every combination *but* this one before arriving.

Comment: Wouldn't you say the convention is `--long-word`? ;)

Answer (score 18):

The simplest solution would be
open terminal

```
$ java -version
```

it shows the following

```
java version "1.6.0_65"
```

2. Stefan's solution also works for me. Here's the exact input:

`$ cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions`

`$ ls -l`

Below is the last line of output:

```
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   59 Feb 12 14:57 CurrentJDK -> /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents
```

1.6.0.jdk would be the answer

Comment: This simply duplicates those two answers.

Answer (score 9):

On modern macOS, the correct path is `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`.

You can also avail yourself of the command `/usr/libexec/java_home`, which will scan that directory for you and return a list.

Answer (score 3):

Which SDKs? If you mean the SDK for Cocoa development, you can check in `/Developer/SDKs/` to see which ones you have installed.

If you're looking for the *Java* SDK version, then open up `/Applications/Utilities/Java Preferences`. The versions of Java that you have installed are listed there.

On Mac OS X 10.6, though, the only Java version is 1.6.

Comment: i am installng intellij. and as i know somwhere in the configuration i 'll need to set jdk. i just wanna make sure that my jdk is updated.

Comment: Note that this answer is *no longer relevant*, as the Java Preferences panel was removed in the [Java 2012-006 update](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4439753?tstart=0).

Comment: For the path "/Applications/Utilities/Java Preferences", it's java applet plug-in

Answer (score 2):

Run this command in your terminal:

```
$ java -version

java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
Cristians-MacBook-Air:~ fa$
```