# React Native error while creating app " Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory()."

Tags: react-native

I tried to do

```
react-native run-android
```

However it comes up with errors

```
--------------
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
> Could not create service of type PluginResolutionStrategyInternal using BuildScopeServices.createPluginResolutionStrategy().

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

    Command failed: ./gradlew installDebug

    Error: Command failed: ./gradlew installDebug
        at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:637:11)
        at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:655:13)
        at runOnAllDevices (/Users/bobbyjulian/Desktop/ReactNative/project/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:299:19)
        at buildAndRun (/Users/bobbyjulian/Desktop/ReactNative/project/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:135:12)
        at isPackagerRunning.then.result (/Users/bobbyjulian/Desktop/ReactNative/project/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:65:12)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had a similar issue here, in my case it was related to access permission.
Just give read access to the project folder.

Command:

`chmod -R 777 YourFolder/`

My log error:

```
spawnSync ./gradlew EACCES

Error: spawnSync ./gradlew EACCES
    at Object.spawnSync (internal/child_process.js:998:20)
    at spawnSync (child_process.js:622:24)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:650:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (/Users/willowchung/project/AwesomeApp/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:299:19)
    at buildAndRun (/Users/willowchung/project/AwesomeApp/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:135:12)
    at isPackagerRunning.then.result (/Users/willowchung/project/AwesomeApp/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:65:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much i had a similar issue.
my issue was the android emulator starts with no problem but application doesn't show up and even log has stopped.
it seems like the application was stuck on something.
when I started the application with "npx react-native run-android" it shows the same error as this issue.
After changing the authority to the project folder as 777, it worked like a charm

Answer (score 7):

```
run chmod 755 android/gradlew
```

that should do the work

Comment: I'm trying to do it but i can't build in android :( after i write `sudo` before command it's work!

Comment: do not include run in comand. chmod 755 android/gradlew will do the work

Answer (score 2):

Check the version of Java JDK you are using. I tried version 11 at first but got the same error you have, then I installed Java JDK version 8 and update the JAVA_HOME setting correctly according [this](https://javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10) therefor problem solved.

Comment: how to check it by using mac? Your link refer to windows OS

Comment: Use this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992566/determining-the-version-of-java-sdk-on-the-mac

Comment: On MacOS try with this in your console: javac -version

Answer (score 0):

This was enough to stop the errors

**1 - INSTALL JDK**

List candidate JDKs:

```
asdf list-all java
```

Install a candidate listed from the previous command like this:

```
asdf install java openjdk-11
```

Select an installed candidate for use like this:

```
asdf global java openjdk-11
```

**2 - Set JAVA_HOME.** To set JAVA_HOME in your shell's initialization add the following:

```
. ~/.asdf/plugins/java/set-java-home.bash
```

For zsh shell, instead use:

```
. ~/.asdf/plugins/java/set-java-home.zsh
```

For fish shell, instead use:

```
. ~/.asdf/plugins/java/set-java-home.fish
```

Answer (score 0):

All errors can be due to different reasons, always in a permissions or gradle context.

In my personal case, updating through Android Studio the gradle version solved my problem, it is automatically given by gradle when starting Android Studio.

Also, you could modify the general permissions in your macOS or through the terminal using `chmod -R 777 or chmod -R 755` with the specific path of your project.

Cheer up!

PS: Sorry for my English, I'm perfecting it, I'm from Chile